# DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated

Tags: python, struct

I have the following problem. The code looks like:

```
import  binascii, struct
def crc32up(data):
    # little endian!!
    bin = struct.pack ('<I', binascii.crc32 (data))
    return string.upper (binascii.hexlify (bin))

# Generate crc of time code.
#
timecrc_code = crc32up(time_code)
```

and the warning is:

```
 DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated
 timecrc_code = crc32up(time_code)
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The value you are trying to pack into the 4 bytes you've assigned for them is too large:

```
>>> import struct
>>> n = 2 ** 32
>>> n
4294967296L
>>> struct.pack('<I', n - 1)
'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> struct.pack('<I', n)
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated
'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Newer python versions (>= 2.6) also give you a warning about the values that *are* accepted:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<I', -1)
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

What python is telling you is that it had to mask the value to fit into 4 bytes; you can do this yourself with `value & 0xFFFFFFFF`.

The warning is issued only once during a python program execution.

Note that as of 2.6 the `binascii.crc32` value is always a *signed* 4-byte value, and you should always use a mask to pack these. This has not always been consistent before 2.6, and depended on the platform. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.crc32) for details.

Comment: I think you're missing a "too large" somewhere in your first sentence.